# Rename AD groups using two PowerShell arrays

Tags: arrays, windows, powershell, scripting, active-directory

I'm trying to rename existing AD groups in this way.

AD groups starting # to be renamed to the same name without #. For example , I have **#dl1** and I wish to get it renamed **dl1** (omitting #)

Im trying to rename following four users first.

[image]

I have written two arrays, in this manner. (**$myArray** and **$myArray2**).

```
$myArray =@(
$data = Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like "#*"} |select samaccountname
$data.samaccountname |  foreach {$_.split("#")[1]
}
)

$myArray2 =@(
$assdf=Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like "#*"}
$myArray2 =@($assdf)
$num=0
foreach($a in $assdf)
{
$myArray2[$num] 
$num=$num+1  
}
)
```

If I print **$myarray** it gives exact results, that I wish, in this way.

[image]

and also if I print **$myarray2** it gives the desired results in this way,

[image]

the missing piece of the puzzle is combining those two arrays to run the final command that is

```
set-adgroup -identity (members indide $myArray2) -samaccountname (members indide $myArray)
```

For hours, I have tried numerous methods to get **set-adgroup** .. using for each loop etc.

**for example,**

```
$a=0 

foreach ($item in $myArray2) 
{
  
 
  $nameto_replace=$myArray[$a]
  Set-adgroup -identity $item.samaccountname -samaccountname $nameto_replace
  $a=$a+1

}
```

Can anyone please shed some light, please? I am totally out of ideas now.  thanks in advance

Comment: try this Foreach ($group in (get-adgroup -f * -searchbase "OU=yourgroup,DC=yourdc" -properties *))
 {
  $NewName = $Group.SamAccountName.Replace("#d*","newnamewat you want")
  set-adgroup $group -SamAccountName $newName -displayname $NewName
  Rename-ADObject $group -newname $newname
  
 }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to perform `Get-ADGroup` twice, where you can use it once and loop over the results in a ForEach-Object loop:

---

**Updated as per [Aravinda's helpful observation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64752429/9898643)**

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -like '#*'" | ForEach-Object {
    $newName = $_.Name.TrimStart('#')
    Write-Host "Renaming group $($_.Name).. to '$newName'"
    # replace only the SamAccountName
    $_ | Set-ADGroup -SamAccountName $newName

    # or replace multiple properties at the same time.
    # You need to use the LDAP names here, so mind the casing !
    # See http://www.selfadsi.org/group-attributes.htm
    # $_ | Set-ADGroup -Replace @{sAMAccountName = $newName; displayName = $newName}
}
```

You can limit the search to a specified OU if you want by adding the OU's DistinguishedName with the `-SearchBase` parameter

Comment: +1 but the last line you commented seems the best answer for the question, not only the samAccountName. `$newName = $_.Name.SubString(1)` can be used either

Comment: single properly change works great ! and replacing multiple instance would be the best option. yet I get an error .. using this $_ | Set-ADGroup -Replace @{sAMAccountName = $newName; cn = $newName; displayName = $newName}

Comment: "Set-ADGroup : The directory service cannot perform the requested operation on the RDN attribute of an object"

Comment: @CFou Thanks. I added that as comment because the OP apparently was only interested in the SamAccountName.

Comment: @Aravinda Ah, sorry about that, I meant property `name`. Changed the code now.

Comment: combination of `Rename-ADObject` and `Set-ADGroup` worked .. all good now!

Answer (score 1):

Theo's answer is fantastic!

Following is the one finally I used derived from theo's answer.

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -like '#*'" | ForEach-Object {
$newName = $_.Name.TrimStart('#')

$_ | Set-ADGroup -Replace @{sAMAccountName = $newName;displayName = $newName} 

$_ | Rename-ADObject -NewName $newName
}
```

If you try using set-adgroup to change **'name'** and **'CN'** and it gives below error.

```
"Set-ADGroup : The directory service cannot perform the requested operation on the RDN attribute of an object"
```

To change multiple attributes, especially including **Name** and **CN**,  combination of `Rename-ADObject` and `Set-ADGroup` can be used.

Comment: Thank you for letting us know. I couldn't try this out myself at the moment. +1