# How to change the case of a group name in Activedirectory using powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory

I am looking to change the case of a group name in AD from Lower to uppercase.
I would like to know if i can run a command directly in Powershell and change it.
Currently i have something which uses a csv file.
For eg: i have a group:
GLB_PERM_AP_SNOW_IT_**Assignment_Group_Managers** i want it to be changed to GLB_PERM_AP_SNOW_IT_**ASSIGNMENT_GROUP_MANAGERS.**
similarly i have around 200 groups to be changed.

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64751065/rename-ad-groups-using-two-powershell-arrays to get you started. Only major difference is rather than `TrimStart('#')` you'll want to use `ToUpper()`

Answer (score 0):

this code will rename the groups in upper case.

```
$adGroups = Get-ADGroup -Filter 'Filter for your groups here' -Properties DisplayName

$adGroups | ForEach-Object {
    $newName = $PSItem.Name.ToUpper()
    $PSItem | Set-ADGroup -DisplayName $newName
    $PSItem | Rename-ADObject -NewName $newName
}
```